# Проблемы с проверкой на одинаковые цифры

Tags: c#

Задание: Выводить ДА если в числе есть 2 и более одинаковые цифры и выводить НЕТ в противном случае

Проблемы: Программа не выводит ДА, когда одинаковые цифры стоят рядом друг с другом

Подскажите что можно сделать...

```
            int all, last, prelast, i; // все число, последняя цифра, предпоследняя цифра, счетчик
            all = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            i = 0;
            DialogResult drs;

            do
            {
                last = all % 10;

                do
                {
                    all = all / 10;
                    prelast = all % 10;
                    if (last == prelast)
                    {
                        i += 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i += 0;
                    }
                }
                while (all != 0);
            }
            while (all != 0);

            if (i != 0)
            {
                drs = MessageBox.Show("Все круто!");
            }
            else
            {
                drs = MessageBox.Show("Не круто(");
            }
```

Comment: На ваши прошлые вопросы есть ответы, но они не приняты. Ознакомьтесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: зачем тут ``else {  i += 0;   }``? Чему равно ``all`` после прохождения внутреннего цикла? Чему будет равно ``last`` на второй итерации внешего цикла? Что делать - переделывать.

Answer (score 2):

Ваша задача имеет более простое решение в несколько строк, используя LINQ.

```
string num = "83913";
var hasSameDigits = num
    .GroupBy(x => x) //Группируем по символам
    .Any(x => x.Count() > 1); //Есть ли хоть одна группа, в которой есть 2 и более символа(цифры)

if (hasSameDigits)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ДА");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("НЕТ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант решения:

- завести массив для подсчёта количества цифр в числе или массив булевых значений
- в цикле пройтись по числу, инкрементируя счётчик цифр/устанавливая соответствующий флажок -- как только значение счётчика превысит 1, вернуть нужный результат
- Печать/вывод результата вынести в отдельный метод

Возможная реализация:

```cs
static bool HasDupDigits(int n) {
    bool[] counts = new bool[10];
    while (n > 0) {
        int digit = n % 10;
        if (counts[digit]) {
            return true;
        } else {
            counts[digit] = true;
        }
        n /= 10;
    }
    return false;
}

static void CheckNumber(int n) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", n, HasDupDigits(n) ? "Круто!" : "Некруто (");
    //MessageBox.Show(HasDupDigits(n) ? "Круто!" : "Некруто (");
}
```

Тест:

```cs
static void Main() {
    CheckNumber(1234);
    CheckNumber(2001);
    CheckNumber(1657206);
}
```

Результат:

```
1234 Некруто (
2001 Круто!
1657206 Круто!
```

---

Аналогично, вместо массива булевых можно использовать одно число и битовые операции:

```java
static bool HasDupDigits(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        int digit = 1 << (n % 10);
        
        if ((count & digit) != 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            count |= digit;
        }
        n /= 10;
    }
    return false;
}
```